# How to prove that the sum of a convergent geometric series of the form $1 + r + r^2 .... + r^n > 1/2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I am trying to prove that the sum of a convergent geometric series of the form 
\begin{equation*}
1 + r + r^2 .... + r^n > \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
but I have no idea how to go about this. Looking at the series, it is pretty obvious, but I just don't know how to prove that this is the case.

If someone wouldn't mind explaining how I would go about proving this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Corey :)

Comment: what is $r$? real, natural, integer?

Comment: Is that a partial sum or are you referring to a geometric series with terms of the form $r^n$?

Comment: If the series converges, what do you know about $r$? And what do you know about the sum of a (convergent) geometric series?

Comment: $1 + r + r^2 .... + r^n=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$

Comment: It is just a polynomial  not a series.

Comment: But if $r=-\frac34$, this is false for $n=1$ and $n=3$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: your inequality is equivalent to
$\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}>\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Whether it converges or not depends on the value of r compared to 1.Follow the hint given by Dr.Sonnard and examine the different cases for $∣r∣<1$ and $∣r∣≥1$.

When you are done with that,you can try looking at the general case of $a+ar+ar^2+...+ar^n+...$ The approach to the answer is identical.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written doesn't make much sense, I'm afraid. But I think what you are trying to say is this:

> Given that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ is convergent, prove that it converges to a value $>\frac12$.

But if the series is convergent, then we have

1. $|r|<1$, and
2. the series converges to $\dfrac{1}{1-r}$.

So all you have to do is show that $\frac{1}{1-r}>\frac12$ whenever $|r|<1$.

Comment: The claim is true for finite, even $n$.

Comment: @Yves: but then what does 'convergent' mean in the OP's question?

Comment: This is meaningless, OP's confusion. But the property is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For odd $n$, you have a polynomial, which ranges in $(-\infty,\infty)$ and the claim cannot hold.

For even $n$, $r\in[-1,0]\implies p(r)=\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\ge\dfrac1{1-r}\ge\dfrac12$. Elsewhere, $p(r)>1$.